# QString fromStdString static function instead of constructor

Tags: c++, qt, api

What is the reason for the choice of API below:

```
QString QString::fromStdString(const std::string & str) [static]
```

Why is there a need for calling a static function when we could have a constructor as follows:

```
QString::QString(const std::string & str)
```

There are similar constructors for the c string representation (char*), std::string being the exception. What is the reason for that?

Comment: I'd actually avoid QString(const char*) and use QLatin1String/QStringLiteral or QString::fromLatin1/QString::FromUtf8 etc. instead, for consciously and explicitly specifying the encoding used for conversion.

Comment: Noted! These calls also happen follow the static function `pattern`...

Comment: I believe this is the factory method pattern at work here... But I don't see they benefit of making an exception for coming strings?

Comment: An alternative could be having the constructor being explicit.

Answer (score 2):

Qt predates `explicit` constructors, and it can't break its existing clients gratuitously. One other reason would be that `std::string` and `QString` are not necessarily in the same encoding/codepage and the static methods make explicit that some more expensive conversion is happening.